# Count multiple column without zero SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to have the following result:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
V1     V2     V3     Result
--------------------------------------------------------
5      10     15     10
4      0      10     7
2      2      0      2
```

My table:

```
--------------------
V1     V2     V3     
--------------------
5      10     15     
4      0      10     
2      2      0
```

What I want to do is, average the column of V1, V2, V3 but without average the zero value. If I am using excel, the formula shoud be:

```
=(V1 + V2 + V3) / COUNTIF(V1, V2, V3, "<>0")
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with a `CASE WHEN`.

```
(V1 + V2 + V3) /
((CASE WHEN V1 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
(CASE WHEN V2 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
etc.))
```

But there might be less verbose ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of the columns divided by sum of sign. Compensate for zero division.

```
SELECT 
  (v1+v2+v3) / nullif(sign(v1) + sign(v2) + sign(v3), 0)
```